# AutoFill - Macro ignora método

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, macro

**Prezados,

Boa tarde! Tenho uma macro que executa alguns processos e segue para o passo de preenchimento de fórmulas, conforme abaixo:

```
BaseSemMO.Range("AD1:AR1").Value = AUXILIAR.Range("AD1:AR1").Value
BaseSemMO.Range("AE2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-12],'4_BASE_PROTOCOLO_448'!C[-30]:C[-22],9,0),""ANTERIOR A 448"")"
BaseSemMO.Range("AF2").FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-1],""MM/AAAA"")"
BaseSemMO.Range("AG2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(RC[-31],'4_BASE_PROTOCOLO_448'!C[-30],1,0)=FALSE,""NÃO"",""SIM""),""NÃO"")"
BaseSemMO.Range("AH2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-3]=""ANTERIOR A 448"",""ANTERIOR A RESOLUÇÃO 448/2019"",""PROTOCOLADO NA RES. 448/2019"")"
BaseSemMO.Range("AI2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-33],'4_BASE_PROTOCOLO_448'!C[-32]:C[-26],7,0),""PROCESSO SEM SOLICITAÇÃO NA 448"")"
BaseSemMO.Range("AJ2").FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-1],""MM/AAAA"")"
BaseSemMO.Range("AL2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(DATEVALUE(RC[-20]),"" "")"
BaseSemMO.Range("AM2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]="" "",""NÃO ANALISADO"",IF(RC[-1]<DATEVALUE(""12/12/2019""),""ANALISADO ANTES DA 448"",""ANALISADO NA 448""))"
BaseSemMO.Range("AN2").FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-2],""MM/AAAA"")"
BaseSemMO.Range("AO2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-10]=""ANTERIOR A 448"",IF(DATEVALUE(RC[-26])<DATEVALUE(""12/12/2019""),RC[-6],DATEVALUE(RC[-26])),RC[-10])"
BaseSemMO.Range("AP2").FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-1],""MM/AAAA"")"
BaseSemMO.Range("AQ2").FormulaR1C1 = "=NUMBERVALUE(RC[-41])"
BaseSemMO.Range("AR2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFS(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'3_AÇÃO_REGRESSO_LISTA_ID_BAJ'!C[-43],1,0)),""NÃO"",RC[-4] = "" "",""SIM"",RC[-4] <> "" "",""NÃO"")"

ESPERA (1)
```

---

Depois do processo acima solicito que ela execute o método AutoFill, porém ele é 'ignorado'.

Tentei com as seguintes opções para tentar fazê-lo funcionar:

- 1ª Opção e não funcionou:

```
LINHAB5T = por volta da linha 180.500

Range("AE2").AutoFill Range("AE2:AR" & lINHAB5T)

ESPERA (1)
    
BaseSemMO.UsedRange.Columns("AE:AR").Calculate
```

- 2ª Opção e não funcionou:

```
Range("AE2:AR2").AutoFill Range(Range("AE2:AR2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 43))

ESPERA (1)
    
BaseSemMO.UsedRange.Columns("AE:AR").Calculate
```

- 3ª Opção e não funcionou:

```
Range("AE2").AutoFill Range("AE2:AE" & lINHAB5T) 'Range(Range("AE2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 43))
Range("AF2").AutoFill Range("AF2:AF" & lINHAB5T)
Range("AG2").AutoFill Range("AG2:AG" & lINHAB5T)
Range("AH2").AutoFill Range("AH2:AH" & lINHAB5T)
Range("AI2").AutoFill Range("AI2:AI" & lINHAB5T)
Range("AJ2").AutoFill Range("AJ2:AJ" & lINHAB5T)
Range("AL2").AutoFill Range("AL2:AL" & lINHAB5T)
Range("AM2").AutoFill Range("AM2:AM" & lINHAB5T)
Range("AN2").AutoFill Range("AN2:AN" & lINHAB5T)
Range("AO2").AutoFill Range("AO2:AO" & lINHAB5T)
Range("AP2").AutoFill Range("AP2:AP" & lINHAB5T)
Range("AQ2").AutoFill Range("AQ2:AQ" & lINHAB5T)
Range("AR2").AutoFill Range("AR2:AR" & lINHAB5T)

ESPERA (1)
    
BaseSemMO.UsedRange.Columns("AE:AR").Calculate
```

- 4ª Opção: não funcionou e apresenta o erro (Erro em tempo de execução '1004':
  "O método AutoFill da classe Range falhou")

```
Set fillRange = Range("AE2:AR" & lINHAB5T)
                                                                                                                                                                        
Range("AE2:AR2").AutoFill Destination:=fillRange
    
    
    If BaseSemMO.Range("AE3") = "" Then
    
        BaseSemMO.Range("AE2:AR2").AutoFill Range(Range("AE2:AR2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 43))
       
    End If

ESPERA (1)
    
BaseSemMO.UsedRange.Columns("AE:AR").Calculate
```

**Tentei os 04 tipos de métodos acima e nenhum funcionou.

Em qualquer um dos métodos acima se for feito pelo passo-a-passo com a tecla F8, eles funcionam funcionam.**

***O que pode ser feito para contornar o erro considerando não perder a eficiência e rapidez?***

Comment: Cara, não sei se entendi direito a pergunta - Algumas macros estão sendo ignoradas, é esse o problema? Será que tu consegues criar um exemplo mínimo verificável que possibilite a comunidade a reproduzir o erro localmente, para poder te ajudar?

Comment: O que acontece? Ele dá um erro, ou não roda de forma silenciosa?

Comment: @CésarRodriguez apesar de eu ter programado para o AutoFill rolar as fórmulas até o final das linhas preenchidas o VBA ou salta a programação ou não lê, pois no final da macro quando vou verificar na planilha só aparece a informação de preenchimento das fórmulas na linha 2.

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado, veja se deixei a pergunta mais clara, por gentileza! Os dados são sigilosos, mas vou providenciar uma planilha com dados fictícios! Obrigado! Você sabe se existe algum problema no Excel-VBA que limite esta verificação pelo AutoFill?

Comment: William, você pode descrever qual é a operação que você faz via interface (com teclado e mouse) que você gostaria de automatizar com autofill? Por exemplo: "eu quero que o excel repita o que aconteceria se eu estivesse com as células AE2:AR2 selecionadas, clicasse no quadradinho preto do canto inferior direito da seleção e descesse, arrastando esse quadrado até a linha 180.000". É essa a operação?

Comment: Se for essa a operação, eu peço que você teste (não arrastando manualmente até a linha 180.000, é claro, mas até a linha 100, por exemplo), e diga se o resultado do autofill foi o esperado.

Comment: Outra coisa: você pode substituir a linha ```LINHAB5T = por volta da linha 180.500``` pela linha de código que você realmente usa? Isso tornaria mais fácil (ou mesmo possível) analisar sua pergunta.

Comment: @CésarRodriguez, em relação ao primeiro questionamento; essa operação que você descreveu é a que o AutoFill faz.
Em relação ao seu segundo questionamento: eu tentei com 100 linhas e o comportamento foi igual, não completou o restante das linhas.
a lINHAB5T é 

lINHAB5T = Worksheets("5_BASE_SOL_ANAL_SEM_MO").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: Mais uma pergunta: depois que você roda a macro e nada acontece, se você clicar numa das células do intervalo autopreenchido, a barra de fórmulas (acima da planilha) também está vazia? A pergunta é porque ele pode ter preenchido a fórmula e somente não renderizado o resultado, ou pode nem ter preenchido as fórmulas.

Comment: Bateu uma ideia de outro método que você não tentou... E se em vez de usar autofill você setar a fórmula já em todas as células do intervalo? No primeiro bloco do seu código, você já colocaria ```BaseSemMO.Range("AE2:AE & lINHAB5T").FormulaR1C1 = ``` etc. Seria uma mistura do primeiro bloco com a tentativa 3.

Comment: @CésarRodriguez, a barra de fórmulas está vazia sim! As células não são preenchidas com as fórmulas. 
Pelo método descrito ```BaseSemMO.Range("AE2:AE & lINHAB5T").FormulaR1C1 = ``` eu tentei, mas ele demora no minimo o dobro do tempo. Por exemplo, toda a Macro sendo executada demora cerca de 6 minutos até o final, com o método acima ela demora 18 minutos para ser executada, desde seu inicio até o final.

Comment: Se demora 6 minutos, é porque você já conseguiu, então?

Comment: @CésarRodriguez, isso quando eu fui inclui o ponto de parada e fiz o passo do AutoFill apertando F8 e depois apertei para continuar.

Answer (score 0):

Analisei sua questão e, realmente, é bizarro o comportamento do XL. Vi que, do nada, o XL alterava para 'Calcula' pelo simples executar da macro.

Repliquei o código aqui e deixei comentadas as linhas que faziam vínculos com outras pastas. Cheguei a essa forma abaixo, que rodou sem falhas. Observe que há outros parâmetros de chamamento do AutoFill, que obtive com o gravador de macros. Utilizo XL 365.

(colei somente a parte do trecho do teste do AutoFill)

```
Dim lngLinha As Long
Dim strRange As Variant

lngLinha = 180500
strRange = "AE2:AR" & lngLinha
Range("AE2").AutoFill Range("AE2:AR18")

Range(strRange).Rows(1).AutoFill Destination:=Range(strRange), Type:=xlFillDefault
```